# Designing and referencing individual xaml resources

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, blend

Here's my situation, I need to make a number of simple vector icons for use in my WPF app, so I figured I would just use `Path`. I want to be able to view the icon as I'm designing it and then reference it as a `StaticResource` in the actual app.

Both Visual Studio and Blend support viewing of `Path` elements in the design view, *provided they are the root element in the xaml file where they are defined*.

But in order to reference the `Path` in the app, it would seem I need to place it inside a `ResourceDictionary`, which can't be viewed in the designer.

Is there any way I can define an xaml resource like `Path` in a file which can be both viewed in the designer and referenced using `StaticResource` within the app?

Comment: Use geometry to define the shape and reference that in your path. Data= staticresource geometrykey

Comment: @Andy But how would you reference the Geometry without putting into a ResourceDictionary ?

Comment: Put geometries in a resourcedictionary.

Comment: @Andy But the problem is that you can’t view resources in a ResourceDictionary in the Visual Studio designer, so I can’t see the icon while I’m designing it.

Comment: While you''re designing what? Merge the resourcedictionary in app.xaml. Stick a path in your view. Set it's data to one of your geometries there it is in your designer.

Comment: @Andy I could do that, but since I’ll be using these icons mainly in DataTemplates, I’d have to make a a separate view just the show these things at design time. It’s not the end of the world, but I was hoping to find a clearer way of doing things.

Comment: You can't view a resourcedictionary in the designer. What i do is obtain a geometry and try it out in a scratch project to check it looks good. Then paste into my resource dictionary in the "real" app.